# RestEasy ContainerRequestContext.abortWith produces java.io.IOException in the client

Tags: java, resteasy

I am developing simple REST Api using RESTEasy. Here are the dependencies I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have simple filter which purpose is to abort incoming requests if the server is already processing N such requests. To be clear, the filter is applied only for the resource we are interested in and it is working fine.

```
@NamedFilter
public class MyCustomFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

private static final Object lock = new Object();
private static int counter  = 0;

private static final int MAX_REQUESTS = 10;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    boolean canProcess = false;
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (counter < MAX_REQUESTS) {
            counter += 1;
            canProcess = true;
        }
        if (!canProcess) {
            // The same behaviour
            // throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.
                            status(503).
                            entity("We cannot process your request now. Try again later").
                            build());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (containerResponseContext.getStatus() != 503) {
            counter --;
        }
    }
}
```

}

So far so good. I was sending the requests using curl and everything was fine. This is the result when the limit is reached.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 

HTTP/1.1 503 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 38
Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2018 09:13:28 GMT
Connection: close

We cannot process your request now. Try again later
```

But the frustration came when I moved from curl to java. If the request limit is not reached everything is working as expected. But when the request cannot be processed instead of status 503 I recieve java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:665)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:677)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1533)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at Main.uploadPOJO(Main.java:135)
    at Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

As I said the java client is working fine if the limit is not reached so assume there is no problem with the code. I will post it later if it is needed. I also tried Appche HTTPClient and got the same result but with different exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
```

And finally my question: Why curl is able to handle this scenario and java not? And most importantly how can I receive the correct status in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you throw throw new WebApplicationException(Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) instead of aborting the request. Curl might be looking at the header whereas the client you are connecting expects the response stream.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I tried but it is the same result.